# How to prepare a BigQuery database to best test different BI systems?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, business-intelligence

We have a database in bigquery that we want to prepare to test different BI systems (looker, chartio, bime, ...).

How should we organize the database?

1. Flatten and normalize
   As a first step we have created normalized and flattened views that we intent to use for BI
2. Combine tables inte huge view
   As I second step we have considered to create a huge view that cross joins all the normalized views into a huge view.
3. Test BI systems
   We intend to initially use this huge view as data source for our tests of BI systems.
4. Split huge view to improve performance
   When we have selected a BI system we intend to create smaller views instead of the huge view to support each dashboard we end up building, to improve speed.

Does this sound like a good approach? Would a different apprach be better?

Answer (score 0):

For BigQuery it makes sense to denormalize the data. Joins are (relatively) expensive. BigQuery is very fast when querying a single table, even if it has >200 denormalized columns. Most of these tools will generate queries on the fly, so if you query a view all the time it will have to do lots of joins for each visualization, and you'll end up waiting a long time.

If you *have* to work with this normalized data, please do all the joins once and "materialize" it by creating a permanent table out of it, and build all your visualizations on top of that.